# Simulink: Make signal available in all subsystems

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a larger model with many subsystems. In some of those subsystems I repeatedly use the same signal (e.g. the exact same noise signal). What is the correct way to make a signal available in all subsystems? I was thinking of *Data Store* or *From/Goto*, but *From/Goto* does no work (for me) with subsystems.
I'm aware, that using *in* blocks would do the trick, but I already have many *in/out* blocks and it just makes the whole model unclear.

Comment: I think it is a better programming practice to be explicit. Just leave it as it is. Else you may forget/accidentally turn on.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I mean that having "global" variables is bad programing practice, better be explicit and make it available by linking it

Comment: I don't want a variable globally availabe, thats the point. Only for the current system and all its subsystems (for only the system I use from/goto, but this does not work for subsystems). This system is embedded in a larger system where this signal is not relevant at all.

Comment: Can you try "goto tag visibility" block? That should make the tags visible in subsystems.